# RegEx - проверка символов начала и конца строки

Tags: регулярные-выражения

С помощью RegEx надо найти слова, состоящие из >=6 цифр и которые могут содержать в начале `+`.
Например, в строке `+1234567 1234568 а1234567 123456` должны быть найдены `+1234567`, `1234568`, `123456`

Сначала я пробовал `\b\\+?\d{6,}\b`
но `\b` включает в себя `+`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

далее я пробовал `(\s)(\\+?\d{6,})(\s)`
но `(\s)` не включает в себя начало и конец строки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как включить в проверку символов начало и конец строки?

Comment: Если честно - не понятно что вы хотите. `Например, в строке "+1234567 1234568 а1234567 123456" должны быть найдены +1234567, 1234568, 123456` и на вашем же скрине они найдены.

Comment: @OwDafuq На первом скрине `+` не зацепило.

Comment: @OwDafuq посмотрите на первое совпадение. Найдены только цифры, нет знака +

Comment: А для `123456+789012` (без пробелов) надо найти `123456` и `+789012`?

Comment: @AlexeyTen нет, из этой строки ничего не должно быть найдено

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Например, в строке "+1234567 1234568 а1234567 123456" должны быть найдены +1234567, 1234568, 123456

Предложу такой вариант...

```js
const s = "+1234567 1234568 а1234567 123456"
const re = /(?<=^|\s)\+?\d{6,}(?=\s|$)/g
console.log(s.match(re))

//Например, в строке "+1234567 1234568 а1234567 123456" должны быть найдены +1234567, 1234568, 123456
```

Answer (score 2):

Тут хорошо смотрятся negative lookahead и negative lookbehind:

```
(?<![^\s])\+?\d{6,}(?![^\s])
```

- `(?<!`...`)` означает "слева нет `...`"
- `(?!`...`)` означает "справа нет `...`"

Я в них передал `[^\s]` - "не пробельный символ", возможно вы захотите что-то другое.